# calculate the pourcentage of the difference between two elements in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the percentage of the different data between two array elements (between two `total`s). How to do that?

```
//...
const [perc, setPerc] = useState(0);

const res = await userRequest.get("orders/income");
setPerc((res.data[1].total * 100) / res.data[0].total - 100);
console.log(res.data);

return(
  <div>{perc}%</div>
)
```

clg `res.data` shows:

```
0: {_id: 11, total: 20}
1: {_id: 12, total: 60}
```

The expected percentage from this data is 33%

The actual percentage is 60%

Comment: Actually `60 * 100 / 20 - 100 = 200`. I think you need to swap `0` and `1` indices and remove `-100`.

Comment: didn't work @sagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to remove the -100 at the end of your setPerc
And if you want the % of the first element relative to the second you also need to swap to [0] and [1]

Comment: thank you so much,  i dont even remember from where -100 comes from!

Comment: hmm weird, i'm sure this should work , i swap [0] and [1] but i'm getting now 49% not 33%